# Fatal Signal 11 exit status

Tags: c, arrays, string, data-structures

The code is giving fatal signal 11 status on a online judge with random test cases tried including array in main and also globally declared but no use.
I know its segmentation fault but unable to debug it. it works fine with smaller test cases.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char a[1101][1101];
int main()
{
    long long int t,m,n;
    scanf("%lld",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int count;
        count=0;
        scanf("%lld %lld",&m,&n);
        //char a[1001][1001];
        long long int l;
        for(l=0;l<m;l++)
        {
               scanf("%s",&a[l]);


        }
        long long int i,j,p=0,b[1101],d[1101],lolo=0,locale=1;
        while(locale==1)
        {
            for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            {   
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {   
                    if(a[i][j]=='r')
                       {
                            b[p]=i;
                            d[p]=j;
                            p++;
                        }   
                }
            }
        //printf("%d\n",p);
            for(i=0;i<p;i++)
            {
             if(a[b[i]-1][d[i]]=='f' && b[i]>=1 && d[i]>=0)
                {   
                  a[b[i]-1][d[i]]='r';
                  lolo=1;
                }
              if(a[b[i]][d[i]+1]=='f' && d[i]<n-1)
              {
                  a[b[i]][d[i]+1]='r';
                  lolo=1;
              }
              if(a[b[i]][d[i]-1]=='f' && d[i]>0)
              {
                  a[b[i]][d[i]-1]='r';
                  lolo=1;
              }
              if(a[b[i]+1][d[i]]=='f' && b[i]<m-1)
              {
                  a[b[i]+1][d[i]]='r';
                  lolo=1;
              }
        }
            //printf("%d lol \n",lolo);
            for(i=0;i<p;i++)
            {
                b[i]=0;
                d[i]=0;
            }
            p=0;
            if(lolo==0)
            {
                for(i=0;i<m;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                        if(a[i][j]=='f')
                        {
                            count=-1;
                            locale=-1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                locale=-1;
            }
            count++;
            lolo=0;
        }
        printf("%lld\n",count-1);
        //printf("%d 00 \n",t);
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<n;j++)
           {
               a[i][j]='\0';
           }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you ignore `scanf()`'s return value you can't expect the program to behave well.

Comment: Just read `scanf()` manual page an learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: Why you assume m,n<1101? Also, your if statements like (a[b[i]][d[i]-1]=='f' && d[i]>0) could lead to error since check for d[i]>0 is done AFTER computing a[b[i]][d[i]-1]. Move it IN FRONT of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a 2D array, and you are reading it using the line

```
 scanf("%s",&a[l]);
```

---

If you want the strings to be stored each one in a different row, then you need to do

```
 scanf("%s",a[l]);
```

Since its a 2D array, `a[l]` means its getting dereferenced once only, and it is giving the starting address of each row.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot a few errors in your code, but there might be more I just can't continue reading because it's hard for me to follow since you declare variables in the middle of the code and you use too little white space so I can't tell what is a variable and what an expression, these are some evident mistakes

1. You maybe use `d` uninitialized, here for example

   ```
   if (a[b[i] - 1][d[i]] == 'f' && b[i] >= 1 && d[i] >= 0)
   ```
2. You pass the address of the pointer to `scanf()` here

   ```
   scanf("%s", &a[l]);
   ```

   althought both `a[l]` and `&a[l]` will be the same addresses, their types will be different and that will affect the pointer arithmetic peroformed on them.
3. You always ignore the return value of `scanf()`, read [this manual page throughly](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and learn how to use `scanf()`. It's still too hard to use it correctly even when you know all this, but it will help you avoid some mistakes.

Comment: Write me a mail iharob@gmail.com